# Excel dynamic number of series

Tags: excel, dynamic, graph

I am trying to dynamically visualize my data for analysis. One thing I want to be able to do is dynamically group the data into different ranges. But I want to be able to change how many ranges that are displayed (up to 6) depending on if they contain non-empty data or not.

So far I have a graph with 6 series, their names correspond to a range given to the left of the graph. The tab with aggregated data contain the data ranges and will update depending on the ranges mentioned above and thus update the graph.

The added functionality I want to create is that when a "From x to y" is set to blanks and the data becomes "0" ("#DIV/0!" since there are no instances in those cases) I want that series to not show up at all in the graph.

The graph:
[image: Graph]

The data:
[image: Data]

Comment: This can be solved with named range and offset. Can you provide how you Select the data? What does `from 3 to 17` do ?

Comment: The tab "Raw" contains the raw data. For each row there is meta-data connected (gender and time in months that is used for this graph) as well as data. The "Aggregated" tab then checks for each row if that person has worked within x-y (inclusive) months and then averages that value. First data-row in "Raw" has 7 months so is included in the first set (3-12 months), but not in any of the other five (42-120, 132-360, and the three 0-0). The last three are empty since no person has 0 months of experience.

Comment: The formula in "Aggregated" for the datapoints is: =AVERAGEIFS(Monitor_10;Station_10;$D10;Time_Months;">="&$N$7;Time_Months;"<="&$O$7)
N7 is the cell in "Aggregated" with the value 3, O7 is the one besides with the value 12. N7 and O7 in turn get their values from "Graphs!B67" and "Graphs!C67" respectively. These are the values in the first picture next to the graph and on the row 67.